# Problems with styled context menuitem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, contextmenu

I have code (below) that should produce a styled context menu.  Unfortunately the menu item also shows a "white" bit that shouldn't be there (see below). I have tried styling it out but it doesn't work.  Any help would be appreciated

[image: Context Menu]

```
    <Style TargetType="ContextMenu">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource backgroundDark}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource highlight}" />
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource highlightLight}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
```

Comment: I've looked through context menu and menu item styles through Blend and I can't see anything that would cause this

Answer (score 1):

you will want to override the

`StackPanel Margin` of MenuItems

and then override with the same value the `ItemsPanel`

[image]

so basically you can just add 2 simple styles in addition to your style.

I have added a sample:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="GlobalMenuItemPanelTemplate">
            <StackPanel Margin="-25,0,0,0" Background="White"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource GlobalMenuItemPanelTemplate}"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Label Background="Bisque" Content="Right Click it" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Label.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Menu item 1" />
                <MenuItem Header="Menu item 2" />
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem Header="Menu item 3" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </Label.ContextMenu>
    </Label>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This works if you add context menu items through XAML but if I do it programmatically through C# (this.ContextMenu.Items.Add(*)) it gives "Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemsPanelTemplate'." as an error

Comment: Also it cuts off the highlight which is not wanted